# React: After successful authentication redirect to PrivateRoute not working

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom

I have created a `Login` component, which redirects me back again to `Login` after successful Authentication. Instead it should redirect to a PrivateRoute at `"/"`. The `handleSubmit` function in my `Login` component looks as follows:

```
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    setLoading(true);
    e.preventDefault();
    authenticationService.login(email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
        history.push("/");
        console.log(authenticationService.isAuthenticated);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error.message || error);
      });
  }
```

I can see that `console.log(authenticationService.isAuthenticated)` is `false` , so the reason why I am redirected to `Login` when `history.push("/")` runs, can be found in the `PrivateRoute` - I am not yet authenticated, so it sends be back to `Login`:

```
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router";
import { authenticationService } from "./services";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if (authenticationService.isAuthenticated) {
        return <Component {...props} />;
      }
      return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }}
  />
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

My question is: What is the recommended way to handle this problem. As this is surely an extremely frequent use case, I guess there is a standard procedure to make this work properly.

In case it is helpful, my `authenticationService.login` looks as follows:

```
// authentication.service.js
import axios from "axios";
import { api } from "../api";

const authAxios = axios.create();

authAxios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const newConfig = config;
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  console.log(token);
  newConfig.headers = {
    Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
  };
  return newConfig;
});

function isAuthenticated() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  return token !== null && token !== undefined;
}

function login(email, password) {
  return axios
    .post(api.auth.login, {
      email,
      password,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.key);
      return res;
    });
}

function logout() {
  localStorage.removeItem("token");
}

const authenticationService = {
  isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated(),
  login,
  logout,
};

export { authAxios, authenticationService };
```

Comment: What is `authenticationService`? Can you show the complete code of it?

Comment: @Tom I included my `authentication.service.js` file - let me know if you need anything else, that might be helpful to you.